SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005 not opening
So far I tried repairing the application but that has not helped. I have also gone through similar questions but with much newer versions of SSMS, but my version does not have the files they mention, for example:
One solution was the find a file called ssms.exe.config, which in my case is called ssmsee.exe., to remove a line that my config file does not have.
Another solution was to copy a file from the directory: C\Program Files(86)....IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Interop to a different folder, but I do not have folder PrivateAssemblies or even the file they mentioned.
I managed to locate the log file but I could not make sense of it myself , see below
2024-07-03 11:17:58.51 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5000.00 (Intel X86) 
    Dec 10 2010 10:56:29 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
    Express Edition on Windows NT 6.2 (Build 9200: )

2024-07-03 11:17:58.51 Server      (c) 2005 Microsoft Corporation.
2024-07-03 11:17:58.51 Server      All rights reserved.
2024-07-03 11:17:58.51 Server      Server process ID is 4140.
2024-07-03 11:17:58.51 Server      Authentication mode is MIXED.
2024-07-03 11:17:58.51 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG'.
2024-07-03 11:17:58.51 Server      This instance of SQL Server last reported using a process ID of 4396 at 7/3/2024 11:17:14 AM (local) 7/3/2024 9:17:14 AM (UTC). This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
2024-07-03 11:17:58.51 Server      Registry startup parameters:
2024-07-03 11:17:58.51 Server        -d c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
2024-07-03 11:17:58.51 Server        -e c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG
2024-07-03 11:17:58.51 Server        -l c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf
2024-07-03 11:17:58.54 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-07-03 11:17:58.54 Server      Detected 12 CPUs. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2024-07-03 11:18:00.61 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2024-07-03 11:18:00.80 Server      Database mirroring has been enabled on this instance of SQL Server.
2024-07-03 11:18:00.82 spid5s      Starting up database 'master'.
2024-07-03 11:18:00.85 spid5s      Recovery is writing a checkpoint in database 'master' (1). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-07-03 11:18:00.91 spid5s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2024-07-03 11:18:00.91 spid5s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2024-07-03 11:18:00.91 spid5s      The resource database build version is 9.00.5000. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-07-03 11:18:00.96 spid8s      Starting up database 'model'.
2024-07-03 11:18:00.96 spid5s      Server name is 'ZAFSIZ-W002\SQLEXPRESS'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-07-03 11:18:00.96 spid5s      Starting up database 'msdb'.
2024-07-03 11:18:00.99 spid8s      Clearing tempdb database.
2024-07-03 11:18:01.13 Server      A self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.
2024-07-03 11:18:01.15 spid8s      Starting up database 'tempdb'.
2024-07-03 11:18:01.16 Server      Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 62548].
2024-07-03 11:18:01.16 Server      Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 62548].
2024-07-03 11:18:01.16 Server      Server local connection provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\SQLLocal\SQLEXPRESS ].
2024-07-03 11:18:01.16 Server      Server named pipe provider is ready to accept connection on [ \\.\pipe\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS\sql\query ].
2024-07-03 11:18:01.16 Server      Dedicated administrator connection support was not started because it is not available on this edition of SQL Server. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-07-03 11:18:01.18 Server      The SQL Network Interface library could not register the Service Principal Name (SPN) for the SQL Server service. Error: 0x54b, state: 3. Failure to register an SPN may cause integrated authentication to fall back to NTLM instead of Kerberos. This is an informational message. Further action is only required if Kerberos authentication is required by authentication policies.
2024-07-03 11:18:01.18 Server      SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2024-07-03 11:18:01.18 spid5s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-07-03 11:18:01.18 spid11s     The Service Broker protocol transport is disabled or not configured.
2024-07-03 11:18:01.18 spid11s     The Database Mirroring protocol transport is disabled or not configured.
2024-07-03 11:18:01.19 spid11s     Service Broker manager has started.
2024-07-03 11:23:00.75 spid11s     Service Broker manager has shut down.
2024-07-03 11:23:00.80 spid5s      SQL Server is terminating in response to a 'stop' request from Service Control Manager. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2024-07-03 11:23:00.82 spid5s      SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.


That's the sql server log, it has nothing to do with client application called SSMS. Why are you using this old hat version on windows 11?

Why are you still using 2005? That reached end of life 8 years ago. It's about a decade past when you should have started to implement your upgrade plan. Considering it's SQL Server Express there is literally no excuse to not be upgrading to a supported version when your edition nears end of mainstream support; Express has been free for years. Of course to upgrade now you're going to also need to find a copy of SQL Server 2012 Express (also end of life), restore/attach the database on there, and then install SQL Server 2022 Express and restore/attach the 2012 database to that.

"So far I tried repairing the application but that has not helped." what happened what error did you see? The log file you shows nothing seriously wrong, but it's not the log for SSMS.

@siggemannen That's the version the company I started working at is using, so those are the cards I have to work with.

@ThomA as I mentioned to siggemannen, the company I'm currently working at has been using it all this time, so I'm left to clean up someone else's mess sadly. Your solution of upgrading to the 2012 version worked great and I was able to restore the database on there. So thank you!

@Charlieface thank you for bringing it to my attention, I thought that would be the correct log file, also there was no error as the program just did not open.

Hopefully you are now upgrading to SQL Server 2022, @Dox ? Honestly, for Express, there really isn't an excuse for a lack of upgrading; if your company hadn't that's just severe negligence. You might not have been in a position there in the past to change that, but hopefully you are now, or at least are in one to educate the business of how concerning that negligence is, and can get them into a supported, and secure, environment.

@ThomA I definitely will be upgrading! Again I really appreciate your help with this.

The solution from @Thom A worked perfectly. Once I found a copy of the 2012 version I was able to restore the database onto there and now everything is back to normal.
